# Using grep in R to delete rows from a data.frame

Tags: r, dataframe, row

I have a dataframe such as this one:

```r
d <- data.frame(x=1,
                y=1:10,
                z=c("apple","pear","banana","A","B","C","D","E","F","G"),
                stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

I'd like to delete some rows from this dataframe, depending on the content of column z:

```r
new_d <- d[-grep("D",d$z),]
```

This works fine; row 7 is now deleted:

```
    new_d
     x  y      z
  1  1  1  apple
  2  1  2   pear
  3  1  3 banana
  4  1  4      A
  5  1  5      B
  6  1  6      C
  8  1  8      E
  9  1  9      F
  10 1 10      G
```

However, when I use grep to search for content that is not present in column z, it seems to delete all content of the dataframe:

```r
new_d <- d[-grep("K",d$z),]
new_d
# [1] x y z
# <0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)
```

I would like to search and delete rows in this or another way, even if the character string I am searching for is not present. How to go about this?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can use TRUE/FALSE subsetting instead of numeric.

`grepl` is like grep, but it returns a `logical` vector.  Negation works with it.

```
 d[!grepl("K",d$z),]
   x  y      z
1  1  1  apple
2  1  2   pear
3  1  3 banana
4  1  4      A
5  1  5      B
6  1  6      C
7  1  7      D
8  1  8      E
9  1  9      F
10 1 10      G
```

Answer (score 7):

Here's your problem:

```
> grep("K",c("apple","pear","banana","A","B","C","D","E","F","G"))
integer(0)
```

Try grepl() instead:

```
d[!grepl("K",d$z),]
```

This works because the negated logical vector has an entry for every row:

```
> grepl("K",d$z)
 [1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
> !grepl("K",d$z)
 [1] TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE
```

Answer (score 4):

For completeness, since R 3.3.0, `grep` and friends come with an `invert` argument:

```r
new_d <- d[grep("K", d$z, invert = TRUE), ]
```

Answer (score 1):

You want to use `grepl` in this case, e.g., `new_d <- d[! grepl("K",d$z),]`.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use `!` or `invert = TRUE` you can also use a REGEX only:

```r
d[ grep('^((?!K).)*$', d$z, perl = TRUE), ]
```

Taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/406230).